# Application Icons in Mono for cross-platform application

Tags: c#, mono, icons, cross-platform

I'm trying to allow my application to use an icon on all platforms for my application which is developed with Mono on Ubuntu Linux.  I have created an SVG 64x64 file that I intended to use for this purpose, but I cant figure out how to do the following:

1)  Allow the application to show in the Ubuntu Unity launch bar with this icon, and to show with this icon in the file manager (Nautilus).
2)  Show in the Mac app bar.
3)  Show as the default application icon in the file browser for windows.

Is there a single platform independent way to do this, or do I need to jump through three hoops (one for each platform) to achieve this?  Any help of any of the platforms would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I never saw any one-for-all solution. For Windows, you need to export an ico file for the SVG image,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511280.aspx

And then in your project file you can specify it as application icon. Then Windows Explorer uses it for your application automatically.

For Ubuntu and OS X, you need other experts help to see how to configure icons.

Comment: Okay, I'm part way there now, I used GIMP to convert the SVG into an ICO, and found a good tutorial on using layers to make each of the ICO standard sizes (16x16, 32x32, 48x48,64x64).  I how have my ICO file.  I found the location under Solution Properties where you can select your application file.  One OS down, two to go! Thx.